# Algoritmo demora 5seg mas a pagina demora 1.5m para carregar

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails, ruby, desempenho

Após chamar um processo via ajax

```
if ($('#content-recommendation').length) {
    $.ajax({
    url:'/get_content_recommendation/' + gon.item_id + '.js',
    type:"get"
  });
}
```

faço o seguinte em `itens_controller/get_content_recommendation`

```
before_action :set_item, only: [:get_content_recommendation,...]
...
def get_content_recommendation
  # GET /itens/1

  start_t = Time.now

  @itens_recomendados_conteudo = @item.get_tf_idf_recommendations

  finish_t = Time.now
  puts "Tempo para realizar todo o processo: " + (finish_t - start_t).to_s + "segundos"

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end

end
```

Em `item#get_tf_idf_recommendations`

```
def get_tf_idf_recommendations

# Esse cara está com problema!

  Item.all.includes(:generos).each do |item|
    aux = Array.new 
    item.generos.each do |gen| 
      aux << gen.id
    end
  data << aux
  end
# -----

# Codigo deveria continuar mas o retorno é apenas para mostrar os itens na view quando o ajax é carregado
return Item.first
end
```

Meu código para alterar o html fica em `views/item#get_content_recommendation.js.erb`

```
$("#content-recommendation").html("<%= 'Apareceu!' %>")
```

O código de `item#get_tf_idf_recommendations` marcado como problematico está por algum motivo **atrasando** a resposta do meu ajax o tempo marcado após a execução pelo `start_t - finish_t` é de `Tempo para realizar todo o processo:`**4.923116s** mas o ajax somente aparece depois de **1m:30s**. Se eu comento o código com problema o texto aparece na hora.

No log não tem nada de anormal:

```
Started GET "/get_content_recommendation/1.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-23 11:29:34 -0300
Processing by ItensController#get_content_recommendation as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Item Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `itens`.* FROM `itens`  WHERE `itens`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Item Load (9.2ms)  SELECT `itens`.* FROM `itens`
  Generalizacao Load (13.4ms)  SELECT `generalizacoes`.* FROM `generalizacoes`  WHERE `generalizacoes`.`item_id` IN (1, 2, ... 1749, 1750, 1751, 1752)

  Genero Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `generos`.* FROM `generos`  WHERE `generos`.`id` IN (1, 12, ... 30, 29)

  Item Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `itens`.* FROM `itens`  LIMIT 5
Tempo para realizar todo o processo: 4.923116segundos
    Rendered itens/_content_recommendation.html.erb (0.8ms)
    Rendered itens/get_content_recommendation.js.erb (2.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4932ms (Views: 5.5ms | ActiveRecord: 24.2ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

**EDITADO:**

Após remover o ajax e carregar em um full request normal, vi que o problema não é o ajax e sim é problema de performance no algoritmo... O tempo ainda é o mesmo **5.03214s** depois disso o log fica:

```
...
Rendered itens/_avaliacoes.html.erb (3.7ms)
Rendered itens/_content_recommendation.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered itens/show.html.erb within layouts/application (693.6ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (5.1ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6396ms (Views: 1194.7ms | ActiveRecord: 61.7ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

Mas a pagina só carrega depois de **1.5m** como pode ser visto pelo trace do Google Chrome:

```
Blocking    0.987 ms
DNS Lookup  624.962 ms
Connecting  0.412 ms
Sending 0.129 ms
Waiting 1.5 min
Receiving 1.441 ms
```

O pior é que não da parar saber o que está demorando e como melhorar!

Answer (score 1):

Seu método está meio confuso, você não precisa usar o .all, veja que o gargalo é o select de todos os itens, uma maneira de deixar mais ruby style seria:

```
def get_tf_idf_recommendations
 itens = Item.includes(:generos)
 itens.generos.map(:id)
end
```

Não sei como está sua modelagem por isso vale testar essa alternativa, se tiver um relacionamento para não precisar buscar em todos os itens vai ajudar, por exemplo: `current_user.orders.itens`.

Uma boa dica é sempre usar a documentação para ver qual o melhor método utilizar e não precisar ficar fazendo código like java, e sim deixar mais legível e dinâmico.

Comment: A modelagem está `|itens|1 --- n|generalizacoes|n ---- 1|generos|` o método está daquele jeito pois preciso que a data seja algo desse tipo `data = [[1, 1, 10, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 21, 24], [1, 37], ...]`para utilizar a gem https://github.com/reddavis/TF-IDF.

A ideia é fazer uma recomendação de itens e para isso preciso pegar todo os itens da base...

O estranho é que a operação demora ~5s mas o html só muda depois de 1.5m, se eu comento o código a resposta é instantânea.